# Do not strip trailing zeros in JavaScript Decimal constructor

Tags: javascript, decimal

i have strings that represents money. E.g 29.00 or 29.10 or 29.13 the currency however can change and does not necessarily lead to a value that has two decimal places by default (Yen for example does not have decimal places at all)

Now, i use Decimal.js to execute calculations with these values

For example i am multiplying with a percentage

```
let d = new decimal("29.00")
let e = d.mul(0.133333333333).toDP(d.decimalPlaces())
```

The result of this however is rounded to 0 decimal places as the constructer strips away the trailing zeros and sets decimalPlaces to 0.

How can i get a decimal value that always has to amount of decimal places provided by the input string? In this example d.decimalPlaces should return 2 (because 29.00 has to decimal places).

Alternative solution: How do i extract the number of decimal places out of the string?

Comment: Does passing it in as a string resolve the issue? `29.00` is a JavaScript number and does not have "trailing zeroes", it's just `29` since that's all you're asking for.

Comment: @tadman: That's almost certainly the solution; definitionally, you can't accurately initialize a decimal with a binary floating point number. Every decimal package I know of suggests using a string for all cases but simple small integer initialization.

Comment: I wouldn't say "binary", I'd say [JavaScript Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), which is by default a floating-point value, and those do not have "trailing zeroes" in their representation. `29`, `29.0` and `29.00000000000000000` are all the same value.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote i have strings but did not put them into the example. I updated the question. I am initializing Decimal with "Number strings"

Comment: As is said. I have money strings coming from a db. "29.00" or even just "29" now i multiply with 0.13333333 or whatever odd number. I NEED the result have execatly the exakt amount of decimal places as it had before. So in case it was "29.00" before it has to be 29*0.1333333= 3.07 after (2 decimal places from "29.00"). But in case the db stored only "29" i need the result to be 3 straight ;)

Comment: @tadman: It's binary floating point; per your own link, the `Number` type is "a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754". Saying it's a JavaScript `Number` just makes the association with general binary floating point more indirect. To be clear, per Wikipedia, "The IEEE standardized the computer representation for binary floating-point numbers in IEEE 754", so it really means the same thing, just more directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Normally when we say "binary" in this context we mean "packed binary" or "opaque binary" that requires some kind of decoding. `Number` does not require any decoding. You can just use it. Calling `Number` binary means everything is called binary. JavaScript code? Binary! Variables? Binary! Obviously, because that's how computers work. That's why when talking about "binary" something more specific is meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
const keepDecimal = (str,mul) => {
  const dec = str.split(".");
  const numDec = dec.length===2?dec[1].length:0;
  return (str*mul).toFixed(numDec);
}

console.log(keepDecimal("29.13",0.133333333333))
console.log(keepDecimal("29",0.133333333333))
```

Comment: Yes, this should do i guess. It does not consider rounding, but i can use the lines above to provide decimal with the correct amoutn of decimal spaces. I will accept this as an Answer

Comment: @DennisH. Note that doing "money math" in any binary floating-point system (like JavaScript) is fraught with peril.

Comment: @Pointy I assumed so. But in the end this is a firebase cloud function which has to be executed on the backend. It will not execute very often but of course still has to work. In the end it has to divide a specific amount between multiple targets so what you saw is part of it. I calculate percentages multiply them and after I check if there are "cents" left which I add or subtract equally over all targets. So in the end I get a valid amount in target currency where each result is at most of by one minor currency unit. I do not work on a "sub"currency precision level

Comment: That's by the way also the reason I am using decimal.js as this works accurately as far as I know